# template or outline for security analysis

Tags: security

I've been asked to come up with a high-level security review of our technology department.  I want to systematically address each of the components of security:  assets, volnerabilites, advisaries.  Anyone know of a template or outline that I could reference?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a template [web app threat model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648866.aspx), in addition to other tools as part of their SDL (secure development lifecycle) resources that might prove useful.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm looking for something a little broader, but this is a good start.